# Create several new columns combining old ones by name

Tags: r, tidyverse

Suppose I have a data.frame or tibble. This object has several columns. Some columns are (`A`, `B`, `C`) are means, and other columns are standard deviations (`A.sd`, `B.sd`, `C.sd`).

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    A=c(1,2,3),
    A.sd=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1),
    B=c(20,2,34),
    B.sd=c(2.1, 5.2, 5.1),
    C=c(14,26,13),
    C.sd=c(1.3, 0.7, 4.5)
  )
```

Now I want to calculate, the coefficient of variation (sd/mean) (this would be `df$A.cv = df$A.sd/df$A`, and so on). I could do it one by one. But I would like to know if maybe the `tidyverse` provides a more automatic way to do this. Some way to match the "mean" columns with the "sd" columns to calculate the "cv" columns.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to make it a wide dataframe with a single column containing the information of the group (A, B, C, etc.) another for means and a third for SD's. then a simple group_by followed with a mutate should be possible (depending on the structure the group_by isn't even necessary I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A canonical & parsimonious approach would be to reshape from wide to long, calculate the CVs and reshape again from long to wide (if necessary).

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(key, value, -row) %>%
    mutate(key = str_replace(key, "^([A-Z])$", "\\1.mean")) %>%
    separate(key, c("var", "col")) %>%
    spread(col, value) %>%
    transmute(row, var = paste0(var, ".cv"), cv = sd / mean) %>%
    spread(var, cv)
#  row       A.cv  B.cv       C.cv
#1   1 0.30000000 0.105 0.09285714
#2   2 0.10000000 2.600 0.02692308
#3   3 0.03333333 0.150 0.34615385
```

This approach is also independent of the order the mean/sd columns are in.

EDIT BY OP:

```
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(key, value, -row) %>%
    mutate(key = str_replace(key, "^([A-Z])$", "\\1.mean")) %>%
    separate(key, c("var", "col")) %>%
    spread(col, value) %>%
    transmute(row, var = paste0(var, ".cv"), cv = sd / mean) %>%
    spread(var, cv) %>% 
    bind_cols(df, .) %>% 
    select(-row)
```

That way the result is in the same data frame and without the "row" column.

Comment: I added an improvement to the answer to meet my preferences. Thank you!

Comment: @Javi_VM You're very welcome & edit approved. You might consider leaving your data in "long" format, which often makes further processing easier and [keeps the data tidier](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf).

Comment: I just realized a problem for selecting the columns in the first `mutate`. Is there a way to use a regular expressions that says "not matching .sd" ? Because the column names do not have to be just one letter.

Comment: @Javi_VM Sure that's definitely possible; a specific solution will depend on the format of your entries. At the moment, `str_replace` matches entries consisting of a single letter, and `separate` splits entries into two columns based on a single separator. Those are the two calls you'd need to adjust. Can you provide a specific example?

Answer (score 1):

You could split your data column-wise (`split.default`) by the first letter of `names(df)` and then use `imap` to generate the `cv` column.

```
library(tidyverse)
split.default(df, f = substr(names(df), 1, 1)) %>% 
  imap(.x = ., ~ mutate(., cv = .x[, paste0(.y, ".sd")] / .x[, .y])) %>% 
  imap(., ~ set_names(., nm = paste0(.y, c("", ".sd", ".cv")))) %>% # rename the columns
  bind_cols()
#  A A.sd       A.cv  B B.sd  B.cv  C C.sd       C.cv
#1 1  0.3 0.30000000 20  2.1 0.105 14  1.3 0.09285714
#2 2  0.2 0.10000000  2  5.2 2.600 26  0.7 0.02692308
#3 3  0.1 0.03333333 34  5.1 0.150 13  4.5 0.34615385
```

`imap` is handy here because it lets you iterate of the list and over the names of that list (the `.y` in the code) easily.

---

The second `imap` call is needed here because strangly this gives an error

```
split.default(df, f = substr(names(df), 1, 1)) %>%
 imap(.x = ., ~ mutate(., paste0(.y, ".cv") = .x[, paste0(.y, ".sd")] / .x[, .y]))
```

---

Same idea but in `base R`

```
lst <- split.default(df, f = substr(names(df), 1, 1))
Reduce(cbind, Map(
  function(x, y)
    `[<-`(x, paste0(y, ".cv"), value = x[, paste0(y, ".sd")] / x[, y]),
  x = lst,
  y = names(lst)
))
```

Comment: A, B, C where names just to make an example. Could you change the solution to make it for a general column name? Like using some regular expression that says "for begining to the first dot". I am not good at all with regular expressions...If I were I would change it myself.

Comment: That is somehow a different question. Please update your post and show enough column names that illustrate the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

using `tidyverse` and `split.default` :

```
df %>% 
  split.default(substr(names(.),1,1)) %>%
  map_dfc(~mutate(., !!paste0(names(.)[1],".cv") := .[[2]]/.[[1]]))
#   A A.sd       A.cv  B B.sd  B.cv  C C.sd       C.cv
# 1 1  0.3 0.30000000 20  2.1 0.105 14  1.3 0.09285714
# 2 2  0.2 0.10000000  2  5.2 2.600 26  0.7 0.02692308
# 3 3  0.1 0.03333333 34  5.1 0.150 13  4.5 0.34615385
```

- The first line splits into 3 data frames depending on 1st character.
- The second line defines a new column called `paste0(names(.)[1],".cv")` (`A.cv` etc) for each data frame and binds everything together.

---

In base R :

```
df_list <- unname(split.default(df,substr(names(df),1,1)))
add_cv  <- function(x) `[[<-`(x, paste0(names(x)[1], ".cv"), value = x[[2]] / x[[1]])
do.call(cbind, lapply(df_list, add_cv))
#   A A.sd       A.cv  B B.sd  B.cv  C C.sd       C.cv
# 1 1  0.3 0.30000000 20  2.1 0.105 14  1.3 0.09285714
# 2 2  0.2 0.10000000  2  5.2 2.600 26  0.7 0.02692308
# 3 3  0.1 0.03333333 34  5.1 0.150 13  4.5 0.34615385
```

---

base R again splitting differently :

```
df_list <- split.default(df, endsWith(names(df),".sd"))
cbind(df, setNames(df_list[[2]] / df_list[[1]], paste0(names(df_list[[1]]), ".cv")))
#   A A.sd  B B.sd  C C.sd       A.cv  B.cv       C.cv
# 1 1  0.3 20  2.1 14  1.3 0.30000000 0.105 0.09285714
# 2 2  0.2  2  5.2 26  0.7 0.10000000 2.600 0.02692308
# 3 3  0.1 34  5.1 13  4.5 0.03333333 0.150 0.34615385
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df  %<>%  mutate(A.cv=A.sd/A,
                B.cv=B.sd/B,
                C.cv=C.sd/C)
```

A better solution is posed below.

Comment: Just a final remark, the "order" is not a fixed thing in the answer section. By default answers are ordered by votes. So words like "below", "2 above me" ... etc are vague. :-)

Comment: The idea of the question is to make it automatically for all columns maching "name" and "name.sd". In the real world I would have a lot more columns, so it would not be efficient to do it this way. But thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you turn it into a long DF Something like this is relatively easy:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
groups = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
means = c(1, 2, 3, 20, 2, 34, 14, 26, 13),
sd = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 2.1, 5.2, 5.1, 1.3, 0.7, 4.5)
)

df <- df %>% mutate(
       cv = (sd / means)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative `tidyverse` version:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    A=c(1,2,3),
    A.sd=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1),
    B=c(20,2,34),
    B.sd=c(2.1, 5.2, 5.1),
    C=c(14,26,13),
    C.sd=c(1.3, 0.7, 4.5)
  )

library(tidyverse)

{df %>% select(matches("sd")) / df %>% select(-matches("sd"))} %>%
  setNames(gsub("sd", "cv", names(.))) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)

#   A A.sd  B B.sd  C C.sd       A.cv  B.cv       C.cv
# 1 1  0.3 20  2.1 14  1.3 0.30000000 0.105 0.09285714
# 2 2  0.2  2  5.2 26  0.7 0.10000000 2.600 0.02692308
# 3 3  0.1 34  5.1 13  4.5 0.03333333 0.150 0.34615385
```

*Note* that you have to make sure your columns are in the right order in your original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data `df` you can use the `dplyr` function `ends_with()` to split the dataset into two, convert to long and bind again:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  data.frame(
    A=c(1,2,3),
    A.sd=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1),
    B=c(20,2,34),
    B.sd=c(2.1, 5.2, 5.1),
    C=c(14,26,13),
    C.sd=c(1.3, 0.7, 4.5)
  )


sds <- select(df, ends_with(".sd")) %>%
  gather() %>%
  rename(sd = value) %>%
  select(sd)

means <- select(df, -ends_with(".sd")) %>%
  gather() %>%
  rename(mean = value)

df_n <- bind_cols(means, sds)

df_n <- mutate(df_n, cv = sd/mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following transformations:

```
df %>%
    # Adding counter
    mutate(n = 1:n()) %>% 
    # Converting to long format
    gather("key", "value", -n) %>% 
    # Adding variable that distinguishes SD and mean
    mutate(type = ifelse(grepl("\\.sd$", key), "SD", "mean"),
           item = sub("(\\w).*", "\\1", key), # A, B, or C
           case = paste(item, n)) %>% # e.g., A 1, B 2, etc.
    select(n, value, type, case) %>% 
    # Conversion back to wide format
    spread("type", "value") %>% 
    # Calculating COV
    mutate(COV = mean / SD)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While answering, please brief on why your solution works. Read this [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more on how to answer. :-)

Comment: The OP should be able to type `?FUNCTIONNAME` into R console and educate himself. That's how I learned all I know today.

Comment: I agree with @AndreElrico. @ben's answer is very good because it provides in the comments the necessary explanations to understand the code. The only thing I dont like is that it does not reverts to the original form of `df` (columns A, A.sd, A.cv, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
IND <- rep(seq(1:(ncol(df1)/2)),each=2)

df1[paste0(names(df1)[!duplicated(IND,F)], ".cv")] <- lapply(split(as.data.frame(t(df1)), IND), function(x)c(t(x)[,2]/t(x)[,1]))

#  A A.sd  B B.sd  C C.sd       A.cv  B.cv       C.cv
#1 1  0.3 20  2.1 14  1.3 0.30000000 0.105 0.09285714
#2 2  0.2  2  5.2 26  0.7 0.10000000 2.600 0.02692308
#3 3  0.1 34  5.1 13  4.5 0.03333333 0.150 0.34615385
```

please note:

- `Base` solution - no third party package needed.
- Is general when the column order is as given.

---

If you want to be dependant on the names, you can use a simple for loop:

```
# name_vec <- LETTERS[1:3]
name_vec <- names(df1)[grepl("^[^.]+$",names(df1))]


for( name_el in name_vec) {
    df1[paste0(name_el, ".cv")] <- df1[[paste0(name_el, ".sd")]]/df1[[name_el]]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is an interesting solution. But I would like to depend on the names more than in the order of columns...

Comment: Interesting, but could you use general names? like using the `names` function but selecting only the ones without dot "." character?

Comment: See the last edit I will make with my answer. Good luck. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
> cv
        A.cv  B.cv       C.cv
1 0.30000000 0.105 0.09285714
2 0.10000000 2.600 0.02692308
3 0.03333333 0.150 0.34615385
```

#### Code

Obviously super-hacky and lots of room for optimization, but probably achieves your goal.

```
cv <- data.frame()
counter <- 0

for (i in 1:ncol(df))(
    if (grepl("sd$", colnames(df)[i]) == TRUE){
        counter <- counter + 1
        for (j in 1:nrow(df))(
            cv[j, counter] <- df[j, i]/df[j, i-1]
        )
        names(cv)[counter] <- paste0(colnames(df)[i-1],".cv")
    } 
)
```

Comment: It is ok, but I was looking for a more elegant solution that does not involve using `for` loops. But maybe it can be converted to a function to simplify its use